# SQL - Function to return the next value of an array if it doesn't exist

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to build a function (on PostgreSQL 9.6.11) with 3 parameters :

- list of ordered values (array of integers)
- value (integer)
- substract (integer)

The aim : if (value - substract) is in the array -> return (value - substract).
If not, I would like to return the next value available in the array (next position)

For example I have this array [2010, 2009, 2008, 2007, 2006, 1999]

If I have value = 2008 and substract = 2, I expect the return 2006 (2006 is in the array)

If I have value = 2008 and substract = 3, I expect the return 1999 (2005 is not in the array, the next value available is 1999)

For now, I'm here :

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION _fonctions_globales.check_year_exist(liste INT[], value integer, substract integer)
 RETURNS integer
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN

    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 WHERE (value - substract) = ANY(liste)) THEN
          return value - substract;
    ELSE 
          return ?;
    END IF;
END; $function$

SELECT _fonctions_globales.check_year_exist(array[2010, 2009, 2008, 2007, 2006, 1999], 2008, 3);
```

Thks for help !

Comment: There are some implied assumptions here, and some ambiguities too.  1). Are the values in the array ***always*** ordered, and ordered descending?  2). If you have `array = [10, 8, 6, 4, 2], value = 9, subtract = 4` I'm assuming the desired return should be `4`?  3). If that's correct, isn't it just a case of ***return the largest value in the array that is less than or equal to `value - subtract`***?  *(Meaning that the order of the array is irrelevant?)*

Comment: Yep, the values in the array are always ordered descending, if the value - substract is not in the array, I take the max value that is less than or equal to value - substract (so I had a condition in the function of a_horse_with_no_name : "AND t.v != value - substract" to do it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a SQL function, no need for PL/pgSQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_year_exist(liste INT[], value integer, substract integer)
 RETURNS integer
AS 
$function$
  select max(v)
  from unnest(liste) as t(v)
  where t.v <= value - substract;
$function$
 LANGUAGE sql;
```

The unnest returns all values as rows, the `where` clause limits that to those smaller than the result of `value - substract` and then highest number is returned. If that is the same as `value - substract` that will be returned, otherwise the next highest.

```
SELECT check_year_exist(array[2010, 2009, 2008, 2007, 2006, 1999], 2008, 3);
```

returns `1999`

```
SELECT check_year_exist(array[2010, 2009, 2008, 2007, 2006, 1999], 2008, 2);
```

returns `2006`